# How can I specify a specific format for each Log4j log level

Tags: java, log4j

First time trying to use log4j version log4j-1.2.17.jar.
On an existing application the client has log4j in place and there is a *log4j.properties* file which specifies a light log output. What I want to do is depending on the log level (ERROR & WARN) output a more refined entry.

On the log4j site I came across this but I think it is to be in some **.xml** file. I need some assistance in understanding how I can put in place the formatting option to alter based on log level.

```
You don't need to declare separate loggers to achieve this. You can set the logging level on the AppenderRef element.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="file" fileName="app.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="file" level="DEBUG"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="INFO"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

1. Would I put this xml content into the web.xml file or another file?
2. a) If another file what file name and where would it go?
3. How do I get log4j to realize that I need it to use the xml file?
4. Will the use of the xml ignore the log4j.properties file?

I know it is a lot of questions but there is only me on the project and the client has a production crisis that needs to be figured out today so I don't have time to go off to read and do tutorials with the client calling me every hour. I figured it may help to get this logging more useful. As the logs are right now I have a date and message output to the log but no idea where the entries are created from without doing extensive searches through the code.

Comment: 1- & 2- This should be saved into logback.xml for example

Comment: Here are some links which would help you.   1> http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/ 2> http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-xml-example/

Comment: The name should be log4j.xml and put into classpath .Create the logger object in class and use that object where you want to print logger. private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class)

Comment: 2 names are specified. Is it logback.xml or log4j.xml? As for creating new objects I cannot alter any code and push to production that is a whole other effort requiring approval ccb etc. So I just need to find a way to get the logging to be more useful right now.

Comment: logback is different framework for logging. Here we are using log4j so the name should be log4j.xml

Comment: If I add in the log4j.xml file to the server will the log4j.properties file be ignored?

Should I remove or comment out the content of the log4j.properties file after putting the log4j.xml file up?

Comment: Yeah remove and place Xml file over there..

Comment: @Elijah hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by defining multiple non-additive Loggers so that the first one only logs errors, the next one warnings and the final one infos and debug.